# Using REGEX to remove duplicates when entire line is not a duplicate

Tags: regex

```
^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$
```

replace with `\1`

The above is a great way to remove duplicate lines using REGEX 
but it requires the entire line to be a duplicate

However – what would I use if I want to detect and remove dups – when the entire line s a whole is not a dup – but just the first X characters

Example:
Original File

```
12345 Dennis Yancey     University of Miami
12345 Dennis Yancey     University of Milan
12345 Dennis Yancey     University of Rome
12344 Ryan Gardner      University of Spain
12347 Smith John        University of Canada
```

Dups Removed

```
12345 Dennis Yancey     University of Miami
12344 Ryan Gardner      University of Spain
12347 Smith John        University of Canada
```

Comment: Which regex engine/language? Are all duplicates consecutive or can they be jumbled in with other lines, e.g. `1 1 2 1` where 1s are duplicates?

Comment: If duplicates are jumbled with potential for other non-duplicate lines to be between two duplicate rows, you can use `^(.{10}).*$[\s\S]*?\K^\1.*`, but you'd have to run it until no more matches are found. This only works in some languages due to `\K` (e.g. PCRE)

Answer (score 3):

How about using a **second [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)** for checking eg the first 10 characters:

```
^((.{10}).*)(?:\r?\n\2.*)+
```

Where [`{n}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions) specifies the amount of the characters from linestart that should be dupe checked.

- the whole line is captured to `$1` which is also used as replacement
- the second group is used to check for duplicate line starts with

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FLrZLS/1)

---

Another idea would be the use of a **[lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** and replace with **empty string**:

```
^(.{10}).*\r?\n(?=\1)
```

This one will just drop the current line, if captured `$1` is ahead in the next line.

[Here is the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FLrZLS/2)

---

For also removing duplicate lines, that contain up to 10 characters, a PCRE idea using conditionals: [`^(?:(.{10})|(.{0,9}$)).*+\r?\n(?(1)(?=\1)|(?=\2$))`](https://regex101.com/r/FLrZLS/6) and replace with empty string.

If your regex flavor supports [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), use of [`.*+` will improve performance](https://regex101.com/r/FLrZLS/5).

Be aware, that all these patterns (and your current regex) just target **consecutive** duplicate lines.